# How to handle onClick event to display text after the click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using react typescript and I’m confused that when I click a button I want some text to appear below the button or at-least anywhere so I made a function to handle the onClick from the button and returned a h1 from the function but turns out no h1 appears on screen after button click. Any idea why?

```
const handleOnClick=(id:any)=>{
    console.log("button clicked" + id)
    return(
      <h1>Clicked it</h1>
    );
```

}
My Function is this and in another function I have

```
<button onClick={()=>{handleOnClick(someId)}}>a</button>
```

I can see the console log but the h1 doesn’t work. Any ideas?

Comment: You mentioned _"when I click a button I want some text to appear below the button"_ and then _"but turns out no `h1` appears on screen after button click."_ So what's the problem?

Comment: Try `document.write`.

Comment: You can't return something from a click handler and hope it renders. Where did you get this idea? If you expect returning `<h1>Clicked it</h1>` from an onClick handler to render that, where is the proof/documentation for that? In the absence of documentation, you cannot assume functionality of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, what your `handleOnClick` doing is returning a bunch of `jsx`, where do you think these `jsx` will appear since we didn't specify any location for them? Now if you try something like this:

```
<button>{ handleOnClick('someId') }</button>
```

You will see the `h1` on the screen because you specify that's where you want to render it, right inside the `button` element.

A classic way in `js` to render out something on button click is like this:

```
const handleOnClick=(e)=>{
   // create the element
   const newEle = document.createElement('h1');
   newEle.innerText = 'Hello';

   // append it inside the button
   e.target.appendChild(newEle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the click is triggered, you need to add the `<h1>` element into your JSX code, and returning it from the click handler is not enough because you need to tell it where is should be added.

A good way of doing that in **React** is by using a state which tells you if the button was clicked or not, and if it was, then you display the `<h1>` element onto the screen. See the code below:

```
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);


const handleOnClick = (id) => {
     console.log("button clicked" + id);
     setIsActive(true);


};
```

and in your JSX code, below the button, you just need to add the second line of the following:

```
<button onClick={()=>{handleOnClick(someId)}}>a</button>
{isActive && <h1>Button was clicked.</h1>}
```

And if you want to toggle the click, So the first time you click the `<h1>` is showing , but if you click again it disappears, then you could simply do this in the `handleOnClick` function instead of the above:

```
const handleOnClick = (id) => {
console.log("button clicked" + id);

    setIsActive((prevState) => (prevState === false ? true : false));
  };
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
    const [nameId, setNameId] = useState<String>("");

    const handleClick = (id: String) => () => {
        console.log("button clicked: ", id);
        setNameId(nameId ? "" : id);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick("Rohan")}>
                {nameId ? "Hide" : "Greet"}
            </button>
            {!!nameId && <h1>Hello {nameId} Haldiya</h1>}
        </>
    );
}
```